# What analyzer should I use so that I get hits for mispelled words?

Tags: java, lucene

I am writing a full text search functionality in my project using Lucene 4.3
Everything works just fine when i add data but when querying I only get hits only if at least one word in the query matches at least one word in the value of a field in the index.

eg if i add

```
private static StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_43);
public static void addCustomerDoc(Map<String, String[]> parameters, String path, long customerId) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(path + "/index/");
    FSDirectory indexDir = FSDirectory.open(file);
    IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_43, analyzer);
    IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(indexDir, config);
    Document doc = new Document();
    doc.add(new TextField("email", parameters.get("email")[0].toString(), Field.Store.YES));
    doc.add(new TextField("username", parameters.get("username")[0].toString(), Field.Store.YES));
    doc.add(new TextField("phone", parameters.get("phone")[0].toString(), Field.Store.YES));
    doc.add(new StringField("customerId", "" + customerId, Field.Store.YES));
    addDoc(writer, doc);
    writer.close();
}

private static void addDoc(IndexWriter writer, Document doc) throws IOException {
    writer.addDocument(doc);
    writer.commit();
}
```

adding a user like

1. username = foobar
2. email = foobar@example.com
3. phone = 0723123456

if i search for foo, fooba or foobarx i get no hits shouldn't I get a result even if I typed f or exceeded the word foobar?

Comment: Some options to look into might be Metaphone and String Distance within lucene.  These can help with getting more fuzzy matches.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the query parser syntax, you should look into [Wildcard](http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html#Wildcard%20Searches) and 
[fuzzy](http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html#Fuzzy%20Searches) query syntax.

You can search for a prefix with funtax like:

```
username:foob*
```

And you can use a fuzzy query instead, with:

```
username:foobarx~
```

Or, you can limit how loose fuzzy querying is, with a number between 0 and 1, higher being more restrictive, like:

```
username:foorbarx~0.5
```